# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose

I am having this error popped up whenever I try to connect to my mongo Server from mongoose.

*I have also tried using different port numbers and deleting the DB file and recreating it. But still the same error log*

**terminal output**

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/Desktop/CRUDJS/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:797:32)
    at /home/Desktop/CRUDJS/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:332:10
    at /home/Desktop/CRUDJS/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/home/Desktop/CRUDJS/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/home/Desktop/CRUDJS/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1153:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/home/Desktop/CRUDJS/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:331:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/Desktop/CRUDJS/app.js:7:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
(node:44838) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:44838) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: add some info to reproduce, like the mongo db docker and the code where you connect

Comment: share you connection string to mongoose